# Why do I get an NaN for my first date parse?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to convert two strings to dates but I am getting an `NaN` for an obviously date string.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

[image: This is where I get the NaN "error"]

Code:

```
function SortMaster() {
        return function (a, b) {
            var aValue = a, bValue = b, aLength = a.length, bLength = b.length;

            var aType = Object.prototype.toString.call(aValue);
            var bType = Object.prototype.toString.call(bValue);

            var aasd = Date.parse(aValue);
            var basd = Date.parse(bValue);

            var aDate = (new Date(Date.parse(aValue))).toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "");
            var bDate = (new Date(Date.parse(bValue))).toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "");


            var highestValue = Math.max(aLength, bLength);

            for (var i = 0; i < highestValue; i++) {

            }
        };
    }
```

---

The value for `a` is a date string `"21.10.2014 14:52:24"`
The value for `b` is also a date string `"04.04.2014 15:04:36"`

Comment: sure, always downvote...

Comment: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please add the code to the question as text, preferably as an executable snippet.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I posted the image to show where my error ocurres

Comment: @Juhana I can add the code but this cannot be executed because it throws the shown error

Comment: Yes, that's the point. People want to try the code and see the error. It's also easier to copy the code to an answer and make corrections, instead of re-typing everything from the image.

Comment: then, why is no one saying this to me and first vote the question down!

Comment: Because your supposed to of [read the help documents](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Actually I didn't down vote, but I posted that link to let you know how to post question to get better response

Comment: @Blobonat 1. please see the edit... 2. the Screenshot is from the debugger. Can you tell me then the issue? Or do I need to tell you my OS and ma Country and stuff?

Comment: This is still no use. What are the values of a and b? Even with the code this still doesn't count as a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read the documents that have been posted in comment here and use the advice to improve this question.

Comment: @Liam see my edit2

Comment: dd.mm.yyyy is not a standard date format. `Date.parse()` interprets it as mm.dd.yyyy. Use a standard yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: @Juhana the time strings are from DOM-Elements and I need to parse them to convert them to another format right?

Comment: You'll have to reformat the string before parsing to a date as @Juhana has suggested, the format you are using simply isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **`a`** is in dd.mm.yyyy format, seems like this is not recognizable as date by javascript which expected an mm.dd.yyyy format, so it threw an error because there's not such month as **`21`**, but for **`b`** the error passed because the day was **`04`** which is less than **`12`** so it considered it as month while in fact it's day, so your format should *not* be dd.mm.yyyy

to demonstrate it check this [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/usq6cmke/3/)

you see `a2` is same date as `a1` just in mm.dd.yyyy and it worked for `a2` but `a1` was invalid date

```js
var a1 = '21.10.2014 14:52:24',
  a2 = '10.21.2014 14:52:24',
  b = '04.04.2014 15:04:36';

var dateA1 = new Date(Date.parse(a1)),
  dateA2 = new Date(Date.parse(a2)),
  dateB = new Date(Date.parse(b));

console.log('a1:' + dateA1); // error, Invalid Date
console.log('a2:' + dateA2);
console.log('b:' + dateB);
```

Comment: Thanks, due to your help I created a function to transfrom the date to a usable format. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the input string have had not the correct date format...

I have now created a function to create a correct format out of a date string.

```
function editDateString(dateString){
    var dateStringSplits = dateString.split(' ');
    var firstPart = dateStringSplits[0];
    var secondPart = dateStringSplits[1];

    var Year = firstPart.split(".")[2];
    var Month = firstPart.split(".")[1];
    var Day = firstPart.split(".")[0];

    var Hour = secondPart.split(":")[0];
    var Minute = secondPart.split(":")[1];
    var Second = secondPart.split(":")[2];

    return newDateString = Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " " + Hour + ":" + Minute + ":" + Second;
}
```

Thanks to Mi-Creativity for his help!!!

Comment: mm/dd/yyyy is also non-standard. If you're rolling your own function, at least return the standard yyyy-mm-dd format for guaranteed compatibility.